# Access form: Datasheet view: How to remove the empty area on the right of the table

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010, whitespace, datasheet

I have a form that is shown in datasheet view. There are 35 fields (columns), so I have to scroll horizontally. It is ok, no problem. The only thing I don't like is that, after last column, a big white space (empty) area appears. It is like if there was a padding or margin on the right of the table.

How can I remove that white space area? (I don't like having to scroll to see only white space)

Answer (score 0):

That's just the way a datasheet works. Think of how an Excel worksheet looks. If you want to control the layout more precisely, you could present the data as a continuous form with many columns and anchor the right edge of the form to the right edge of the window. But then you would sacrifice the power of the datasheet view (two-way compatibility with Excel, etc.).